# How can I use Kotlin to handle asynchronous speech recognition?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

The Code A is from the artical https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/async-recognize

It write with Java, I don't think the following code is a good code, it make the app interrupt.

```
while (!response.isDone()) {
     System.out.println("Waiting for response...");
     Thread.sleep(10000);
}
...
```

I'm a beginner of Kotlin. How can I use Kotlin to write the better code? maybe using coroutines ?

**Code A**

```
public static void asyncRecognizeGcs(String gcsUri) throws Exception {
  // Instantiates a client with GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
  try (SpeechClient speech = SpeechClient.create()) {

    // Configure remote file request for FLAC
    RecognitionConfig config =
        RecognitionConfig.newBuilder()
            .setEncoding(AudioEncoding.FLAC)
            .setLanguageCode("en-US")
            .setSampleRateHertz(16000)
            .build();
    RecognitionAudio audio = RecognitionAudio.newBuilder().setUri(gcsUri).build();

    // Use non-blocking call for getting file transcription
    OperationFuture<LongRunningRecognizeResponse, LongRunningRecognizeMetadata> response =
        speech.longRunningRecognizeAsync(config, audio);
    while (!response.isDone()) {
      System.out.println("Waiting for response...");
      Thread.sleep(10000);
    }

    List<SpeechRecognitionResult> results = response.get().getResultsList();

    for (SpeechRecognitionResult result : results) {
      // There can be several alternative transcripts for a given chunk of speech. Just use the
      // first (most likely) one here.
      SpeechRecognitionAlternative alternative = result.getAlternativesList().get(0);
      System.out.printf("Transcription: %s\n", alternative.getTranscript());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Sure you can use Coroutines but, maybe it's overkill to learn Coroutines just to run this code asynchronoulsy. To be clear I'm a fan of Coroutines they are great to deal with such situations. To try to help you you should specify where you are planning to integrate the recognition (mobile? back end?). Coming to the while loop I think it's here just to provide a feedback during Future execution. The thread will be stopped anyway to wait for the result by response.get()

Comment: You could use coroutines to avoid blocking the thread with a `get()` if there is a listener/callback mechanism present on this `OperationFuture` that you get from the `SpeechClient`. But indeed the while loop doesn't seem necessary anyway even in this code.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to provide some context to understand what you are trying to achieve, but it looks like coroutine is not really necessary here, as `longRunningRecognizeAsync` is already non-blocking and returns OperationFuture response object. You just need to decide what to do with that response, or just store Future and check it later. There is nothing implicitly wrong with `while (!response.isDone()) {}`, that's how Java Futures are supposed to work. Also check OperationFuture, if its normal Java Future, it should implement `get()` method, that will let you wait for result if necessary, without having to do explicit Thread.sleep().

Comment: Thanks! Do you mean I may serialize the object of `response` to a string, and later I get the object `response` from the string using unserialize, then fire  then opeation `!response.isDone()` to get result?

Comment: And will the Google Cloud keep the object `respones` a long time?